# Getting scroll position and automatically scrolling a material-ui table

Tags: reactjs, scroll, material-ui

I want to be able to get the position of the scroll and automatically scroll a material-ui table (https://v4.mui.com/components/tables/#virtualized-table) so that when I leave the page and return, I could automatically scroll back to where I stopped.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Example that you sent uses package `react-virtualized`, which you have to install. The `Table` component which you can import from this package has `onScroll` prop.

Make a handler function with saving results to local storage, add `ref` to `Table` and call `scrollToPosition` method, such as:

```
import React, {useState, useRef, useEffect} from 'react';
import { Table, Column } from 'react-virtualized';
import {axios} from 'helpers';

function App() {

    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const ref = useRef();

    const {scrollTop} = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data'));
    
    useEffect(() => {
        axios
            .get('https://random-data-api.com/api/address/random_address?size=100')
            .then(res => {
                setData(res);
                ref.current.scrollToPosition(scrollTop)
            })
    }, [scrollTop]);

    const handleScroll = data => {
        const {scrollTop} = data;
        if(scrollTop > 50) {
            localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(data))
        }
    };

    return (
        <Table
            ref={ref}
            rowCount={data.length}
            width={300}
            height={300}
            headerHeight={20}
            rowHeight={30}
            rowGetter={({index}) => data[index]}
            onScroll={handleScroll}
            scrollToIndex={10}
        >
            <Column label="City" dataKey="city" width={100} />
        </Table>
    )
}
```

P.S. Code may be unoptimized and have some errors.